# facebook like button not appearing <fb:like>

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I have added a facebook like button with this code:

```
<div id="fblike"><fb:like id="aa" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" ></fb:like></div>
```

The problem is that it works only on Chrome and IE.
How is it possible?
In Firefox it is not showing.
You can see it at: http://judopassion.com/wordpress/?p=274

When you go forward to the image gallery, a pop-up will appear with the button.

What may be the problem?[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it only does not work in Firefox, my guess would be this problem:

[Facebook Like buttons not displaying when loaded hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291017/facebook-like-buttons-not-displaying-when-loaded-hidden)

Btw, i only see one like button on your page, and that is right next to the article, always visible in every browser. If i click on the arrows in the gallery, there´s only a popup with countdown. When the countdown is over i can browse through the pictures. No sign of an additional like button.

Comment: i did not see that in any browser...but i guess it´s solved now :)