# Facebook LIKE Button Missing After JQuery.Toggle in Firefox

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have an odd issue that only seems to happen on Firefox.  I have two DIV's I am toggling between to see different pre-loaded content.  The LIKE button code is identical, but after I toggle to the other code, the LIKE buttons on the content that was not originally showing are not there.  If I toggle back, the LIKE buttons originally showing are still there and fine.  It's only the ones that were not initially showing.

See example here: http://www.upcomingevents.com/o/upcoming-events-167/

Anyone have any ideas?

Again, this works fine Chrome, just not Firefox.  ODD!!

Thanks in advance,

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution after some more searching.

[Facebook Like buttons not displaying when loaded hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291017/facebook-like-buttons-not-displaying-when-loaded-hidden)

The fbAsyncInit answer works like a charm.

Hope this helps someone.

Dennis